# Transferring Onclick Function to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that replaces thumbnails with the main image.
This is the code that I use for replacing the main image:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wheelFinishThumbs a").click(function() {
    var mainImage = $(this).attr("href");
    var mainTemp = mainImage.replace(/-mid/,'');
    var mainTemp = mainTemp.replace(/png/,'jpg');
    $("#main_view img").attr('src', mainImage );
    $("#main_view a").attr('href',mainTemp);
    return false;       
    });
```

I use a PHP function to download (save) images by changing their header values. This is the HTML code that I use to download images

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('download.php?file=image.jpg','_self', 'download', 'status=0');">Click to download</a>
```

but since "image.jpg" has to be my dynamic variable some how I've got to call this argument in the jQuery image replacement function and replace "image.jpg" dynamically each time I change the main image. I want to replace image.jpg with `var mainImage` from my image swapping function.

My jQuery knowledge is really limited, so If somebody can help me to do it, would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, assuming you are using jQuery 1.7+

Assuming your a tag markup is like this after you dynamically set the href to new image

```
<a href="urltoSomeImage.jpg" id="main_view">Download Image</a>
```

JavasScript

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click","#main_view",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var self=$(this);
      alert("replace this with awesome code")

      window.open('download.php?file='+self.attr("href")+,'_self', 'download', 'status=0');
  });
});
```

Note that this function will work only of a single a element because we are targeting binding the functionality to the element with id main_view. Since ID's should be unique in the  DOM, If you want to have the functionality to many a tags, i would add a common class selector to the a tag like this

```
<a class="aDownloadble" href="urltoSomeImage2.jpg" id="main_view">Download Image2</a>
<a class="aDownloadble" href="urltoSomeImage4.jpg" id="main_view">Download Image4</a>
```

And Update my script like this

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click",".aDownloadble",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var self=$(this);
      alert("replace this with awesome code")

      window.open('download.php?file='+self.attr("href"),'_self', 'download', 'status=0');
  });
});
```

jQuery `on` is nnot necessary. you can simply use the `click` event binding directly. But if you are loading the markup of those links via ajax / injecting to the DOM dynamically, you should use `on` or `live`.

Comment: window.open('download.php?file='+self.attr("href")+,'_self', 'download', 'status=0'); dreamweaver marksup this line red

Comment: @AykunCetinkaya: Ah ! We had an extra + in the window.open statement. I corrected it now. ( just before '_self')

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(){

    $("#main_view a").click(function() {
     // Code to run when user clicks on link
    });
});
```